# Image appears on image when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/Informasjon_button.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/Mail_button.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/Facebook_button.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/TLF_button.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/Portfolio_button.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I need another image to appear while hovering over the current image.

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far? We aren't going to do all the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know of your needs. Would you like us to finish the rest of your code? what have you tried?

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

give your div's an id>

something like:

html:

```
<div id="image1"> <a href="#"> <img src="images/Informasjon_button.png" width="120px" height="120px" /></a><span class="overlay"></span></div>
```

css:

```
.image1:hover .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: transparent url('image2.png') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="one"></div> 
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="two"></div>  
 </a>
```

add style

```
<style type="text/css">
    .one{
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       /*background: url('icn.png') no-repeat;*/
       background-color: #0080FF;
    }
    .two{
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       /*background: url('icn.png') no-repeat;*/
       background-color: #8000FF;
    }
    .one:before{
      content: '';
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px; 
      /*background: url('icn.png') no-repeat;*/
      background-color: #008040;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .two:before{
       content: '';
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px; 
      /*background: url('icn.png') no-repeat;*/
      background-color: #FF0080;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .one:hover:before, .two:hover:before{
      width: 0px;
      -webkit-animation: animation .2s 1 linear;
    }
       @-webkit-keyframes animation{
       from{width: 100px}
       to{width: 0px;}
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make these buttons images. I suggest using the technique of **css sprite**. 
Basically you will use the hover to change the image itself. 
Here's a link to better understand http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Bye.

**If the solution please voteup.*